# Set a single returned result from sql query as a variable

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query that is returning a single result.  I would like to set that as a variable value in the query to be used later on.  It shows up often with all the sub querys that I have.
So I would like to

```
DECLARE @NEWID AS INT = 55
```

| IdNumber |
| --- |
| 55 |

Answer (score 0):

There's 2 ways to get a value from a table into a variable.

1. Set

```
DECLARE @NEWID AS INT;

SET @NEWID = (SELECT MAX(ID)+1 FROM SomeTable);
```

But the query may only return a single value.

2. Select

```
DECLARE @NEWID AS INT;

SELECT @NEWID = MAX(ID)+1 
FROM SomeTable;
```

The variable will become the last value that would be returned by the query.